# PHP displaying stored time data, and storing time data while accounting for different timezones

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, datetime

I am creating this post, to get confirmation that i am understanding the process correctly, and also to get feedback on a few minor details on solving the issue of post times being displayed and stored correctly for users in various time-zones.

**Storing the time**

First step is getting the users timezone as a GMT offset format using a javascript function, and storing it in a session variable. For example, the $timezone variable will store GMT -4

```
$timezone=$_SESSION['time'];
```

Next, Once i have my users timezone. When the user makes a post, I store the post time in mysql database, I will need to store it as a UTC format. How do i do this? Currently when I store the time data. it is in the following way. My stamp field is datetime format, and i would like to leave it as such if possible.

```
INSERT INTO posts (stamp) VALUES (now())
```

What function do i use instead of now() to get the UTC format which will then be inserted into my database? I assume that I need to use a php function which will use the $timezone to produce the UTC date.

**Displaying the time**

Next, Once the UTC date is stored in the db. I need to display the data to the user based on the $timezone variable we set.

So when I display the time, I currently do

```
echo date('F d', strtotime($list1['stamp']));
```

Once i have stored the data as UTC time, this will display the UTC time, but i need to show the user the UTC offset for their timezone, so I will need to convert `$list['stamp']` in UTC time to a the users timezone using $timezone. What function do i user for this?

**tl:dr**
This should be all I need to make this work. let me know if you see any suggestions, or items that i have not accounted for, and if you know what functions I need to use to convert the time to UTC to store in the database, and what function to use to convert the UTC time to display user, using the $timezone variable.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but I've found the DateTime class and its setTimezone method pretty useful in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inserting UTC time into the database:

```
INSERT INTO posts (stamp) VALUES (UTC_DATE())
```

**UPDATE:** This will only insert the YYYY-MM-DD into your database. If you need time as well, then use:

```
INSERT INTO posts (stamp) VALUES (UTC_TIMESTAMP())
```

Then for printing the date according to timezone:

```
$date = date_create($list1['stamp'], timezone_open($timezone)); //$timezone='Pacific/Nauru';
echo date_format($date, 'F d');
```

That should help get you started. Learn more about PHP's [DateTime Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for Object Oriented Methods, and cleaner programming in general.

Comment: Awesome thanks. does the timezone_open() require that $timezone='Pacific/Nauru' or can $timezone='GMT -4' if the former, how do i convert GMT -4 to 'Pacific/Nauru' (ie converting the offset to the timezone name.)

Comment: I think you need the mysql function UTC_TIMESTAMP() not UTC_DATE()

Comment: cool thanks. I should store the date using UTC_TIMESTAMP instead of UTC_DATE? is this related to the my_sql stamp database field being datetime format?

Comment: i did some research and found that a way to convert the GMT offset to a timezone name such as 'Pacific/Nauru' is by using the echo timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3600, 1) . "\n"; function. will this work?

Comment: UTC_DATE() will only store de date.

Comment: @arboles Yes, timezone_name_from_abbr is what you want to convert to the proper strings.

Comment: @arboles UTC_DATE will use the YYYY-MM-DD format, while UTC_TIMESTAMP() will use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. I was a little unclear as to which you needed, so I will update.